# Clashing background and foreground colors on "Visit Stack Exchange" button

Tags: bug, design, stack-exchange-button

When you open the Stack Exchange menu on certain sites, the button that says "Visit Stack Exchange" has a blue color that doesn't match the button's background color.

[image]

Some sites like this are:

- [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)
- [Role-playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)

...